# Sitecore Placeholder Setting

Tags: sitecore, placeholder, sitecore8

Do I really have to set Placeholder Settings for rendering items in Presentation Detail??

I have many placeholder settings (without adding into Presentation Detail) and I can see empty placeholders areas (gray-box) without any problem. Then, I can choose assigned rendering items from the selected empty placeholder.

However, whenever I update files in "/App_Config" or "/bin" folder, all empty placeholder areas are disappeared (No gray-box) if the placeholder setting was not added into Presentation Detail. So, in Content Editor, I go to placeholder setting items which have the issue, then edit and save again and refresh the xEditor page. Now, the saved Placeholder Setting item appears.

What is the problem??? When App Pool recycles, is there something removing placeholder thing?? I have no idea...

I'm using Sitecore 8.0 and dynamic binding like `@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("Placeholder Key Name")`

Comment: I don't fully understand your issue. If you set the Allowed Controls in the Placeholder setting (under `/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings`) then that should be enough as "Global Placeholder Settings": http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/maximizing-usability/posts/2012/08/the-power-of-placeholder-settings.aspx

Comment: @jammykam Yes. I think so. However, once Sitecore's App Pool recycles, the global placeholder setting doesn't apply until I just edit and save the placeholder item in "Placeholder Setting" tree. :(

Comment: That shouldn't be happening by default in Sitecore. I don't suppose you're using [Unicorn with Transparent Sync](http://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/10/Unicorn-Introducing-Transparent-Sync/) by any chance?

Comment: @jammykam Thank you for the info. I will try to take a look at. Many thanks!